# Getting Firebase data in recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a RecylerView adapter class that is for user created *posts*. What I am trying to do is retrieve the post authors information through Firebase and then bind that information into the post in `onBindViewHolder()`

My problem is that when I call `getPostAuthorInfo()` (which is just used to get the data from firebase) in `onBindViewHolder()` the method is asynchronous, so I am not able to bind the properties as so because the data (mUser) is not yet ready:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(mUser.getProfilePictureImageUrl()).into(viewHolder.authorsProfilePicture);
```

Could someone help me understand if I am approaching this the wrong way, or just not doing it correctly?

Thank You.

```
    private void getPostAuthorInfo(final String userId) {
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String firstName = "";
            String lastName = "";
            String dateAccountCreated = "";
            String email = "";
            String userId = "";
            String username = "";
            Boolean isMale = false;
            Boolean isFemale = false;
            Boolean isOther = false;
            String biography = "";
            String location = "";
            String profilePictureImageUrl = "";
            String profilePictureImageName = "";
            String profilePictureCaptionName = "";
            HashMap <String, String> profileInformation = new HashMap<>();
            for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                firstName = (String) snapshot.child("firstName").getValue();
                lastName = (String) snapshot.child("lastName").getValue();
                dateAccountCreated = (String) snapshot.child("dateAccountCreated").getValue();
                email = (String) snapshot.child("email").getValue();
                userId = (String) snapshot.child("userId").getValue();
                username = (String) snapshot.child("username").getValue();
                isMale = (Boolean) snapshot.child("male").getValue();
                isFemale = (Boolean) snapshot.child("female").getValue();
                isOther = (Boolean) snapshot.child("other").getValue();
                biography = (String) snapshot.child("biography").getValue();
                location = (String) snapshot.child("location").getValue();
                profilePictureImageUrl = (String) snapshot.child("profilePictureImageUrl").getValue();
                profilePictureImageName = (String) snapshot.child("profilePictureImageName").getValue();
                profilePictureCaptionName = (String) snapshot.child("profilePictureCaptionName").getValue();
                profileInformation = (HashMap) snapshot.child("profileInformation").getValue();
            }
            mUser = new User(userId, firstName, lastName, username, email, isMale,
                    isFemale, isOther, dateAccountCreated, biography, location,
                    profilePictureImageUrl, profilePictureImageName, profilePictureCaptionName, profileInformation);
            Log.i(TAG, "Currently signed in user: " + mUser.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to retrieve signed in user", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: man post the whole code , you just posted an irrelevant Picasso stuff

Comment: Have you considered using the FirebaseUI library?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes. I'm just too far in using normal adapters to switch now.

Comment: What are you trying to display? `mUser` is only one instance of a user, so you are going to get every ViewHolder showing the same information...

Answer (score 1):

Is a "post" a single thing and you just want the author info?

You can extract your callback into the method for the recommended async method call pattern.

```
private void getPostAuthorInfo(final String userId, ValueEventListener listener) {
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
}
```

Then wherever you call that method, you can get access to your imageview.

```
ImageView authorsProfilePicture; 
Context mContext;

api.getPostAuthorInfo("id-xyz", new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        String profilePictureImageUrl = (String) snapshot.child("profilePictureImageUrl").getValue();

        Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(profilePictureImageUrl)
            .into(authorsProfilePicture);
    }
});
```